# Show recent items in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, global-variables

I am trying to make a recent items functionality that will show the user a list of the recent viewed (viewed by him) records. This is my idea to make it work:

1. Create a global array variable that will store the last 5 viewed objects

   @@recent_items= Array.new(5)
2. Every time a Controller Method Model#show is executed, the record will be inserted in the array @@recent_items. Replacing the first inserted record (FIFO).
3. Then show the @@recent_items array on my application.html.erb view

Does this make sense? What would be a better way to do it?

---

Results:
I did a test hardcoding a record just to see how it would work.

application_controller.erb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     @@recent_items     = Array.new(5)
     @@recent_items[0]  = Account.find(1)
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= @@recent_items[0].name %>
```

And I got an error:

```
NameError in Accounts#show
Showing /Users/xyz/rails_projects/crm/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #52 raised:

uninitialized class variable @@recent_items in ActionView::CompiledTemplates
```

Comment: Global variables are preceded with a $ sign, eg. $global_variable

Comment: You want to store something like that in the session. Global variables or class variables will be constantly overwritten by other users.

Comment: Yes - store ids in the session as a comma delimited string

Comment: Storing in the session looks good! I want to retrieve two attributes from the object, such as: id and name. I have read that storing objects in the session is not a very good idea. Sounds like I should build an Arrays of Hashes, right?